# Use Material Icons in XML

Tags: android, material-design

I want to use the new material icons provided by Google. I find it a bit cumbersome to download each icon individually. 
Is there a way to do something like:

```
<ImageButton
  android:src="@android:Icon.Material.IconName"
  .../>
```

If not, whats the easiest way to include multiple icons in my project? 
Cheers.

Comment: You can use this website to download free material icons by Google : https://design.google.com/icons/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Follow these steps to start Vector Asset Studio:

In Android Studio, open an Android app project.
In the Project window, select the Android view.

```
Right-click the res folder and select New > Vector Asset.
```

After you open Vector Asset Studio, you can add a material icon as follows:

Select "Material Icon"

Click Choose

Select a material icon

Answer (score -2):

Checkout if this can be helpful:

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons